# Convert HashMap to ArrayList with identical sort

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following problem: I have a HashMap

```
HashMap <String, BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima> dataBeanList = new HashMap ();
```

And I am generating an iReport report, but to send the data to the report, I do a HashMap conversion to an ArrayList:

```
List <BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima> test = new ArrayList <BeanRelEstatisticaMateriaPrima> (dataBeanList.values ());

JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource (test);
```

But in doing this conversion, ordination is being lost. In the hashmap I have in alphabetical order, eg:
(A, B, C, D, E) but in the ArrayList it gets (D, A, E, C, B)

Is there a way to transform to ArrayList by keeping the sort order exactly the same as HashMap?

Comment: "In the hashmap I have in alphabetical order" I'm not convinced you do. Hashmaps have no ordering guarantee. Perhaps you insert them in that order; however, they will be inserted into the list in the iteration order.

Comment: try with a LinkedHashMap, instead of hashMap.

Comment: TreeMap also preserve insert order.

Comment: @gawi no, it doesn't. It orders according to either natural order, or a provided comparator.

Comment: you might be right, I'm using it to have deterministic order, but never paid attention if it's insertion order, thx for pointing it out

Comment: Thanks to all for your help.

I used LinkedHashMap and it was correct.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashMaps do not guarantee order. Use a LinkedHashMap if you want to preserve order of insertion.

Comment: Thanks to all for your help.

I used LinkedHashMap and it was correct.

Thank you.